# How do I mock an open used in a with statement (using the Mock framework in Python)?

Tags: python, mocking, with-statement

How do I test the following code with [`unittest.mock`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/unittest.mock.html):

```
def testme(filepath):
    with open(filepath) as f:
        return f.read()
```

Answer (score 158, accepted):

The way to do this has changed in mock 0.7.0 which finally supports mocking the python protocol methods (magic methods), particularly using the MagicMock:

http://www.voidspace.org.uk/python/mock/magicmock.html

An example of mocking open as a context manager (from the examples page in the mock documentation):

```
>>> open_name = '%s.open' % __name__
>>> with patch(open_name, create=True) as mock_open:
...     mock_open.return_value = MagicMock(spec=file)
...
...     with open('/some/path', 'w') as f:
...         f.write('something')
...
<mock.Mock object at 0x...>
>>> file_handle = mock_open.return_value.__enter__.return_value
>>> file_handle.write.assert_called_with('something')
```

Comment: Wow! This looks much simpler than the context-manager example currently at http://www.voidspace.org.uk/python/mock/magicmock.html which explicitly sets `__enter__` and `__exit__` to mock objects as well — is the latter approach out of date, or still useful?

Comment: The "latter approach" is showing how to do it *without* using a MagicMock (i.e. it is just an example of how Mock supports magic methods). If you use a MagicMock (as above) then __enter__ and __exit__ are preconfigured for you.

Comment: you could point to your [blog post](http://www.voidspace.org.uk/python/weblog/arch_d7_2010_10_02.shtml#e1188) where you explain in more details why/how that works

Comment: In Python 3, 'file' is not defined (used in the MagicMock spec), so I'm using io.IOBase instead.

Comment: Note: in Python3 the builtin `file` is gone!

Comment: All I had to read was "...use MagicMock" and that solved it. I was using create_autospec() not realizing the file object had to be a MagicMock.

Comment: What's the value of file?

Comment: It seems you can avoid the explicit `MagicMock` doing `with patch('builtins.open', spec=io.IOBase) as mock:`

Comment: I'm confused. Why is `mock_open` still available in the outer scope?

Answer (score 429):

## Python 3

Patch [`builtins.open`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/builtins.html) and use [`mock_open`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/unittest.mock.html#mock-open), which is part of the [`mock`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/unittest.mock.html#module-unittest.mock) framework. [`patch`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/unittest.mock.html#patch) used as a [context manager](https://docs.python.org/3/reference/datamodel.html#with-statement-context-managers) returns the object used to replace the patched one:

```
from unittest.mock import patch, mock_open
with patch("builtins.open", mock_open(read_data="data")) as mock_file:
    assert open("path/to/open").read() == "data"
mock_file.assert_called_with("path/to/open")
```

If you want to use `patch` as a decorator, using `mock_open()`'s result as the `new=` argument to `patch` can be a little bit weird. Instead, use `patch`'s `new_callable=` argument and remember that every extra argument that `patch` doesn't use will be passed to the `new_callable` function, as described in the [`patch` documentation](https://docs.python.org/3/library/unittest.mock.html#patch):

> `patch()` takes arbitrary keyword arguments. These will be passed to the `Mock` (or *new_callable*) on construction.

```
@patch("builtins.open", new_callable=mock_open, read_data="data")
def test_patch(mock_file):
    assert open("path/to/open").read() == "data"
    mock_file.assert_called_with("path/to/open")
```

Remember that in this case `patch` will pass the mocked object as an argument to your test function.

## Python 2

You need to patch `__builtin__.open` instead of `builtins.open` and `mock` is not part of `unittest`, you need to `pip install` and import it separately:

```
from mock import patch, mock_open
with patch("__builtin__.open", mock_open(read_data="data")) as mock_file:
    assert open("path/to/open").read() == "data"
mock_file.assert_called_with("path/to/open")
```

Comment: Grazie! My problem was a bit more complex (I had to channel the `return_value` of `mock_open` into another mock object and assert the second mock's `return_value`), but it worked by adding `mock_open` as `new_callable`.

Comment: How should I code my test to work on both py2 and py3? I don't like the idea of checking `sys.version_info` during the test

Comment: @ArthurZopellaro take a look to `six` module to have a consistent `mock` module. But I don't know if it map also `builtins` in a common module.

Comment: How do you find the correct name to patch? I.e. how do yo find the first argument to @patch ('builtins.open' in this case) for an arbitrary function?

Comment: @zenperttu You have to know what function you're invoking. `open()` is part of Python's builtin functions (see https://docs.python.org/3/library/builtins.html). A different example: if you open a file using `pathlib.Path.open()`, you need to patch accordingly: `@patch('pathlib.Path.open', new_callable=mock_open)`.

Comment: Please note you may need to refine your assertions. I get `AssertionError. Expected: open('file_path') Actual: open('file_path', 'r', -1, None, None)`

Answer (score 86):

With the latest versions of mock, you can use the really useful [mock_open](http://www.voidspace.org.uk/python/mock/helpers.html#mock-open) helper:

> **mock_open(mock=None, read_data=None)**
>
> A helper function to create a
>   mock to replace the use of open. It works for open called directly or
>   used as a context manager.
>
> The mock argument is the mock object to configure. If None (the
>   default) then a MagicMock will be created for you, with the API
>   limited to methods or attributes available on standard file handles.
>
> read_data is a string for the read method of the file handle to
>   return. This is an empty string by default.

```
>>> from mock import mock_open, patch
>>> m = mock_open()
>>> with patch('{}.open'.format(__name__), m, create=True):
...    with open('foo', 'w') as h:
...        h.write('some stuff')

>>> m.assert_called_once_with('foo', 'w')
>>> handle = m()
>>> handle.write.assert_called_once_with('some stuff')
```

Comment: how do you check if there are multiple `.write` calls?

Comment: @naxa One way is to pass each expected parameter to `handle.write.assert_any_call()`. You can also use `handle.write.call_args_list` to get each call if the order is important.

Comment: `m.return_value.write.assert_called_once_with('some stuff')` is better imo. Avoids registering a call.

Comment: Manually asserting about `Mock.call_args_list` is safer than calling any of the `Mock.assert_xxx`, methods. If you mis-spell any of the latter, being attributes of Mock, they will always silently pass.

Answer (score 17):

To use [mock_open](https://docs.python.org/3.3/library/unittest.mock.html#mock-open) for a simple file `read()` (the original mock_open snippet [already given on this page](https://stackoverflow.com/a/19146253/552793) is geared more for write):

```
my_text = "some text to return when read() is called on the file object"
mocked_open_function = mock.mock_open(read_data=my_text)

with mock.patch("__builtin__.open", mocked_open_function):
    with open("any_string") as f:
        print f.read()
```

Note as per docs for mock_open, this is specifically for `read()`, so won't work with common patterns like `for line in f`, for example.

Uses python 2.6.6 / mock 1.0.1

Comment: Looks good, but I can't get it to work with `for line in opened_file:` type of code. I tried experimenting with iterable StringIO that implements `__iter__` and using that instead of `my_text`, but no luck.

Comment: @EvgeniiPuchkaryov This works specifically for `read()` so won't work in your `for line in opened_file` case; I've edited the post to clarify

Comment: @EvgeniiPuchkaryov `for line in f:` support can be achieved by mocking the return value of `open()` as [a StringIO object instead](http://stackoverflow.com/a/24325868/696485).

Comment: To clarify, the system under test (SUT) in this example is:
    `with open("any_string") as f:
        print f.read()`

Comment: For Python 3+, just change `__builtin__` to `builtins`: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9047745/where-is-the-builtin-module-in-python3-why-was-it-renamed. For the record, `builtins` is the module containing all top-level functions, see documentation:https://docs.python.org/3/library/builtins.html (edit: see updated answer a bit below for more details)

Answer (score 10):

If you don't need any file further, you can decorate the test method:

```
@patch('builtins.open', mock_open(read_data="data"))
def test_testme():
    result = testeme()
    assert result == "data"
```

Answer (score 7):

The top answer is useful but I expanded on it a bit.

If you want to set the value of your file object (the `f` in `as f`) based on the arguments passed to `open()` here's one way to do it:

```
def save_arg_return_data(*args, **kwargs):
    mm = MagicMock(spec=file)
    mm.__enter__.return_value = do_something_with_data(*args, **kwargs)
    return mm
m = MagicMock()
m.side_effect = save_arg_return_array_of_data

# if your open() call is in the file mymodule.animals 
# use mymodule.animals as name_of_called_file
open_name = '%s.open' % name_of_called_file

with patch(open_name, m, create=True):
    #do testing here
```

Basically, `open()` will return an object and `with` will call `__enter__()` on that object.

To mock properly, we must mock `open()` to return a mock object. That mock object should then mock the `__enter__()` call on it (`MagicMock` will do this for us) to return the mock data/file object we want (hence `mm.__enter__.return_value`). Doing this with 2 mocks the way above allows us to capture the arguments passed to `open()` and pass them to our `do_something_with_data` method.

I passed an entire mock file as a string to `open()` and my `do_something_with_data` looked like this:

```
def do_something_with_data(*args, **kwargs):
    return args[0].split("\n")
```

This transforms the string into a list so you can do the following as you would with a normal file:

```
for line in file:
    #do action
```

Comment: If the code being tested handles the file in a different way, for example by calling its function "readline", you can return any mock object you want in the function "do_something_with_data" with the desired attributes.

Comment: Is there a way to avoid touching `__enter__`? It definitely looks more like a hack than a recommended way.

Comment: __enter__ is how conext managers like open() are written. Mocks will often be a bit hacky in that you need to access "private" stuff to mock, but the enter here isnt ingerintly hacky imo

Answer (score 4):

I might be a bit late to the game, but this worked for me when calling `open` in another module without having to create a new file.

test.py

```
import unittest
from mock import Mock, patch, mock_open
from MyObj import MyObj

class TestObj(unittest.TestCase):
    open_ = mock_open()
    with patch.object(__builtin__, "open", open_):
        ref = MyObj()
        ref.save("myfile.txt")
    assert open_.call_args_list == [call("myfile.txt", "wb")]
```

MyObj.py

```
class MyObj(object):
    def save(self, filename):
        with open(filename, "wb") as f:
            f.write("sample text")
```

By patching the `open` function inside the `__builtin__` module to my `mock_open()`, I can mock writing to a file without creating one.

Note: If you are using a module that uses cython, or your program depends on cython in any way, you will need to import [cython's `__builtin__` module](https://docs.python.org/2/library/__builtin__.html) by including `import __builtin__` at the top of your file. You will not be able to mock the universal `__builtin__` if you are using cython.

Comment: A variation of this approached worked for me, as the majority of the code under test was in other modules as shown here.  I did need to make sure to add `import __builtin__` to my test module.  This article helped clarify why this technique works as well as it does: http://www.ichimonji10.name/blog/6/

Answer (score 3):

#### To patch the built-in open() function with unittest:

This worked for a patch to read a json config.

```
class ObjectUnderTest:
    def __init__(self, filename: str):
        with open(filename, 'r') as f:
            dict_content = json.load(f)
```

The mocked object is the io.TextIOWrapper object returned by the open() function

```
@patch("<src.where.object.is.used>.open",
        return_value=io.TextIOWrapper(io.BufferedReader(io.BytesIO(b'{"test_key": "test_value"}'))))
    def test_object_function_under_test(self, mocker):
```

Comment: This is what worked for me in Python 3.7+

Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

I'm using `pytest` in my case, and the good news is that in Python 3 the `unittest` library can also be imported and used without issue.

Here is my approach. First, I create a `conftest.py` file with reusable pytest fixture(s):

```py
from functools import cache
from unittest.mock import MagicMock, mock_open

import pytest
from pytest_mock import MockerFixture


class FileMock(MagicMock):

    def __init__(self, mocker: MagicMock = None, **kwargs):
        super().__init__(**kwargs)

        if mocker:
            self.__dict__ = mocker.__dict__
            # configure mock object to replace the use of open(...)
            # note: this is useful in scenarios where data is written out
            _ = mock_open(mock=self)

    @property
    def read_data(self):
        return self.side_effect

    @read_data.setter
    def read_data(self, mock_data: str):
        """set mock data to be returned when `open(...).read()` is called."""
        self.side_effect = mock_open(read_data=mock_data)

    @property
    @cache
    def write_calls(self):
        """a list of calls made to `open().write(...)`"""
        handle = self.return_value
        write: MagicMock = handle.write
        return write.call_args_list

    @property
    def write_lines(self) -> str:
        """a list of written lines (as a string)"""
        return ''.join([c[0][0] for c in self.write_calls])


@pytest.fixture
def mock_file_open(mocker: MockerFixture) -> FileMock:
    return FileMock(mocker.patch('builtins.open'))
```

Where I decided to make the `read_data` as a property, in order to be more pythonic. It can be assigned in a test function with whatever data that `open()` needs to return.

In my test file, named something like `test_it_works.py`, I have a following test case to confirm intended functionality:

```py
from unittest.mock import call


def test_mock_file_open_and_read(mock_file_open):
    mock_file_open.read_data = 'hello\nworld!'

    with open('/my/file/here', 'r') as in_file:
        assert in_file.readlines() == ['hello\n', 'world!']

    mock_file_open.assert_called_with('/my/file/here', 'r')


def test_mock_file_open_and_write(mock_file_open):
    with open('/out/file/here', 'w') as f:
        f.write('hello\n')
        f.write('world!\n')
        f.write('--> testing 123 :-)')

    mock_file_open.assert_called_with('/out/file/here', 'w')

    assert call('world!\n') in mock_file_open.write_calls

    assert mock_file_open.write_lines == """\
hello
world!
--> testing 123 :-)
""".rstrip()
```

Check out the gist [here](https://gist.github.com/rnag/0a73feb229ae580e545903ea3c040a01).

Answer (score -1):

Sourced from a github snippet to patch read and write functionality in python.

The source link is over [here](https://gist.github.com/curzona/0616d4752f44f2ff8914)

```
import configparser
import pytest

simpleconfig = """[section]\nkey = value\n\n"""

def test_monkeypatch_open_read(mockopen):
    filename = 'somefile.txt'
    mockopen.write(filename, simpleconfig)
 
    parser = configparser.ConfigParser()
    parser.read(filename)
    assert parser.sections() == ['section']
 
def test_monkeypatch_open_write(mockopen):
    parser = configparser.ConfigParser()
    parser.add_section('section')
    parser.set('section', 'key', 'value')
 
    filename = 'somefile.txt'
    parser.write(open(filename, 'wb'))
    assert mockopen.read(filename) == simpleconfig
```

Answer (score -2):

**SIMPLE @patch with assert**

If you're wanting to use @patch. The open() is called inside the handler and is read.

```
    @patch("builtins.open", new_callable=mock_open, read_data="data")
    def test_lambda_handler(self, mock_open_file):
        
        lambda_handler(event, {})
```