# How can I write tests that populates raw_post_data and request.FILES['myfile']

Tags: django, unit-testing

I have something like this:

```
def upload_something(request):
    data = {}
    if request.FILES:
        raw_file = request.FILES['myfile'].read()
    else:
        raw_file = request.raw_post_data
```

I can't seem to be able to write a unit-test that populates `raw_post_data`, how would I go about doing that? I basically just want to send an image file. I'm trying to create a test case for when I read `raw_post_data` and it errors with:

> You cannot access raw_post_data after reading from request's data stream

Answer (score 4):

I'm assuming you have figured this out by now, but as the answers are almost out of date with the deprecation of raw_post_data I thought i'd post.

```
def test_xml_payload(self):
    data = '<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?><blah></blah>'
    response = self.client.post(reverse('my_url'),
                                data=data,
                                content_type='application/xml')


def my_view(request):
    xml = request.body
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use mocking. Some examples available [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1289894/how-do-i-mock-an-open-used-in-a-with-statement-using-the-mock-framework-in-pyth) and in docs [here](http://www.voidspace.org.uk/python/mock/examples.html#mocking-open)

---

### Updated

Kit, I think it's very depends on your test case. But in general you shouldn't use raw_post_data directly. Instead it's have to be patched like in example below:

```
from mock import Mock, MagicMock

class SomeTestCase(TestCase):

    def testRawPostData(self):
        ...

        request = Mock(spec=request)
        request.raw_post_data = 'myrawdata'
        print request.raw_post_data  # prints 'myrawdata'

        file_mock = MagicMock(spec=file)
        file_mock.read.return_value = 'myfiledata'
        request.FILES = {'myfile': file_mock}    
        print request.FILES['myfile'].read()  # prints 'myfiledata'
```

Comment: The test case I'm trying to cover is that when I read `raw_post_data` it's telling me that I've already read the data before, which I don't think would be possible to hit via Mock.

Comment: Kit, I'm just updated the answer. If you still sure that the mocking doesn't cover your needs, please provide your tests code.

Answer (score 1):

The error message the interpreter is giving is correct. After you access the POST data via `if request.FILES`, you can no longer access the raw_post_data. If in your actual code (not the tests) you hit that line, it would error with the same message. Basically, you need two separate views for form-based POSTS and direct file POSTS.

Answer (score 0):

I took this listing [here](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/testing/)

```
c = Client()
f = open('wishlist.doc')
c.post('/customers/wishes/', {'name': 'fred', 'attachment': f})
f.close()
```

Client is a special class for testing your views. This is the example of posting files to your view. It's part of Django testing framework.