# mock file objects passed within json in python

Tags: python, json, file, mocking

how to mock the following using MagicMock in Python 2.6.6:

```
with open('filename.txt', 'rb') as f:
    json.dumps(json.load(f))
```

Comment: Create a StringIO in place of f.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yay, I found the solution, this is my approach:

```
@patch("json.load", MagicMock('{cool}')
@patch("json.dumps", MagicMock(return_value='{cool}'))
```

Comment: @Micheled'Amico: A little harsh IMO

Answer (score 0):

You can use [`mock`](https://docs.python.org/dev/library/unittest.mock.html#module-unittest.mock) framework [(install it by `pip`)](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/mock). Use [`patch`](https://docs.python.org/dev/library/unittest.mock.html#the-patchers) and [`mock_open`](https://docs.python.org/dev/library/unittest.mock.html#mock-open) by following this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/34677735/4101725).

Answer (score 0):

I append `json.dumps()`.endcode("utf-8")