# Mocking builtin function open inside an imported module

Tags: python, unit-testing, ftp, mocking

I want to test that the `ftp.storbinary()` function is called with the right arguments. This however is part of a different module from the one were the test live.

In the `io.py` module I have this method (which is part of a class):

```
def to_ftp(self, output_path, file_name, host, username, password):
    """Upload file to FTP server."""

    ftp = ftplib.FTP(host)
    ftp.login(username, password)
    full_path = os.path.join(output_path, file_name)
    with open(full_path, "r") as ftp_file:
        ftp.storbinary(" ".join(["STOR", file_name]), ftp_file.read)
```

I've create a `test_io.py` module where I have a series of unittests. I was thinking to patch both `open` and `ftplib.FTP`, because I'm passing to `ftp.storbinary()` `ftp_file.read()`.

```
@patch("ppc_model.io.ftplib.FTP")
def test_store_call(self, mock_ftp):
    """The *storbinary* call must use the right arguments."""

    with patch("ppc_model.io.open", mock_open(read_data=None)) as m:
        self.writer.to_ftp(output_path="./output", file_name="output.zip",
                       host="myftp", username="username", password="password")
    mock_ftp.return_value.storbinary.assert_called_once_with(
    "STOR output.zip", m.read())
```

This however returns an AttributeError because the module doesn't have an attribute `open`. How can I make sure Mock understand I'm trying to mock the builtin function?

Is there also a better way to test I'm passing the right arguments to `ftp.storbinary`? I'm kinda new to mocking.

**EDIT:** I've made some progress. I think the issue was that I was trying to patch the wrong object. With `open` I think I have to patch `builtins.open`. A bit counter-intuitive.

```
@patch("ppc_model.io.ftplib.FTP")
def test_store_call(self, mock_ftp):
    """The *storbinary* call must use the right arguments."""

    with patch("builtins.open", mock_open(read_data=None), create=True) as m:
        self.writer.to_ftp(output_path="./output", file_name="output.zip",
                       host="myftp", username="username", password="password")
    mock_ftp.return_value.storbinary.assert_called_once_with(
    "STOR output.zip", m.read())
```

Unfortunately now the compiler is complaining about the fact that the Mock object doesn't have a `read` method.

`AttributeError: Mock object has no attribute 'read'`

**EDIT 2:** Following RedCraig's advice I've patched the `open` method in the local namespace and passed to `ftp.storbinary` ftp_file instead of ftp_file.read()). So the current unit test is:

```
@patch("ppc_model.io.ftplib.FTP")
def test_store_call(self, mock_ftp):
    """The *storbinary* call must use the right arguments."""

with patch("{}.open".format(__name__), mock_open(read_data=None),
           create=True) as m:
    self.writer.to_ftp(output_path="./output", file_name="output.zip",
                   host="myftp", username="username", password="password")
mock_ftp.return_value.storbinary.assert_called_once_with(
"STOR output.zip", m)
```

And the code I'm trying to test:

```
def to_ftp(self, output_path, file_name, host, username, password):
    """Upload file to FTP server."""

    ftp = ftplib.FTP(host)
    ftp.login(username, password)
    full_path = os.path.join(output_path, file_name)
    with open(full_path, "r") as ftp_file:
        ftp.storbinary(" ".join(["STOR", file_name]), ftp_file)
```

The current error I get is:

```
AssertionError: Expected call: storbinary('STOR output.zip', <MagicMock name='open' spec='builtin_function_or_method' id='140210704581632'>)
Actual call: storbinary('STOR output.zip', <_io.TextIOWrapper name='./output/output.zip' mode='r' encoding='UTF-8'>)
```

Comment: If `open` is the python builtin, then does: `with patch("open", ...` work? The way you're testing the args looks fine.

Comment: Yes `open` is the python builtin, however `with patch("open", ...` doesn't work.

Answer (score 1):

> AssertionError: Expected call: storbinary('STOR output.zip', )
>
> Actual call: storbinary('STOR output.zip', <_io.TextIOWrapper name='./output/output.zip' mode='r' encoding='UTF-8'>)

For the actual call `storbinary` was given `<_io.TextIOWrapper...` rather than the mocked object. Seems like the mocking of `open` isn't working, perhaps your module name is incorrect.

Here are the [unittest.mock examples](https://docs.python.org/3/library/unittest.mock-examples.html), this page has an example of mocking open:

```
>>> mock = MagicMock(return_value=sentinel.file_handle)
>>> with patch('builtins.open', mock):
...     handle = open('filename', 'r')
...
>>> mock.assert_called_with('filename', 'r')
>>> assert handle == sentinel.file_handle, "incorrect file handle returned"
```

I tried mocking open in another module and it works, there's a catch when using it with `assert_called_once_with()`. When patching open mock uses a MagicMock object, every call to `open()` returns a new object. So the test case which patches `open` using a `with as m` style statement will have a different value for `m` than the open call from `to_ftp` ad `assert_called_once_with()` will fail.

While I'm sure there's a better way with `Mock` and `assert_called_once_with`, I resorted to using a `StringIO` object when mocking `open` so that each call returns the *same* `StringIO` instance:

```
import ftplib
import os

from io import StringIO
from unittest import TestCase
from unittest.mock import patch


def to_ftp(output_path, file_name, host, username, password):
    """Upload file to FTP server."""
    ftp = ftplib.FTP(host)
    ftp.login(username, password)
    full_path = os.path.join(output_path, file_name)
    with open(full_path, "r") as ftp_file:
        ftp.storbinary(" ".join(["STOR", file_name]), ftp_file)


class TestOpenMock(TestCase):
    @patch("ftplib.FTP")
    def test_store_call(self, mock_ftp):
        """The *storbinary* call must use the right arguments."""
        open_file = StringIO('test_data')
        with patch('%s.open' % __name__, return_value=open_file):
            to_ftp(output_path="./output", file_name="output.zip",
                   host="myftp", username="username", password="password")

        mock_ftp.return_value.storbinary.assert_called_once_with(
            "STOR output.zip", open_file)
```

This passes. Obviously you'll have to change your `'%s.open' % __name__` to your module containing `to_ftp`.

---

### Original Answer (@any so mod: should I just delete this?):

1) This looks like the answer you're looking for:
[How do I mock an open used in a with statement (using the Mock framework in Python)?](https://stackoverflow.com/a/6112456/2175385)
It mocks `open` using `<local module name>.open`.

2)

> AttributeError: Mock object has no attribute 'read'

It's complaining about the read because you're passing the read method to `storbinary`:

```
ftp.storbinary(" ".join(["STOR", file_name]), ftp_file.read)
```

and your mocked instance of open `ftp_file` doesn't have that method.

3) You're checking that `storbinary` was called with `m.read()` but you're passing in `m.read`. `m.read()` invokes the read method whereas `m.read` is a reference to the method.

```
mock_ftp.return_value.storbinary.assert_called_once_with("STOR output.zip", m.read())
```

4) Looking at the docs for [`ftp.storbinary`](https://docs.python.org/2.7/library/ftplib.html#ftplib.FTP.storbinary), it expects the file object itself, not a reference to the file objects `read` method. It should be:

```
ftp.storbinary(" ".join(["STOR", file_name]), ftp_file)
```

Passing in the (mocked) file object will address point 3) above.

Comment: I've edited the question to reflect your suggestions. Thanks!