# Can I mock `open` (and other builtins) when testing my functions?

Tags: python, python-unittest, python-unittest.mock

When writing unit tests, I can use `unittest.mock` to isolate dependencies and monitor use of the mocked functions. Can I do the same with calls to builtin functions?

In particular, it would be nice to mock `open()` so that I can provide test input, or monitor output, without involving disk files. Is this possible, and adviseable? (I already know this can be done, without mocking, for functions that accept an open file object rather than a filename.)

Comment: You can define your own `open`, your own `print`, whatever... You can have a string called `open`, a `unittest.mock` called `open`. These would shadow the builtin.

Comment: Thanks for the tip, @Wyatt! I'll see if the solution works with `unittest.mock`, and if it does I'll close my question.

Comment: Indeed it works... the [answer by Michele d'Amico](https://stackoverflow.com/a/34677735/699305) (the second answer), not the accepted one.