# How to mock the load of pickle file?

Tags: python, mocking, pytest

I have a production code to test (code_to_test) presented which requires me to mock the test of loading of pickle file to do some validations further.

```
def code_to_test():
  #need to mock the below line
  with open("path/to/file/model.pickle", "rb") as pickle_file:
     model_dictionary = dill.load(pickle_file)
  #some other stuff to validate based on the mock
```

I mocked as follows

```
from unittest.mock import patch
with patch("path.of.module.code_to_test.dill.load") as _mock:
     _mock.return_value = some_dictionary_fixture
```

But it failed to test stating

When I tried to mock as follows, it shows up

> ModuleNotFoundError

**Update:**
I also tried to Patch `builtins.open` and use `mock_open` (Like so - https://stackoverflow.com/a/34677735/7641555 ). But I am not sure how to use it to mock my case.

Comment: `mock` is part of unittest and you aren't showing your imports, so I'm going to assume you didn't import it.
https://docs.python.org/3/library/unittest.mock.html

Comment: Why don't you extract the file loading? Either pass the loaded content in, or call a function that returns it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

your patch is ~slightly off -- you're including the function but you should not:

```py
from unittest.mock import patch
with patch("path.of.module.dill.load") as _mock:
     _mock.return_value = some_dictionary_fixture
```

but, you don't even need that -- since `dill` is imported as a module you can patch that directly:

```py
import dill
from unittest import mock
with mock.patch.object(dill, 'load', return_value=some_dictionary_fixture):
    ...
```