# how can a test Writing file operation with @pytest.fixture

Tags: python, mocking, pytest

I'm practicing unittest in python and i'm stuck with a problem
I  have a module that contains read/write file operations

my project structure is it

. name_project:

```
    --src
        -palindromoClass.py
        -lerEscreveArquivo.py
        -main.py
    --tests
        -test_palindromo.py
```

```
import os

def abreArquivo(nomeArquivo:str)-\>list\[str\]:

    if not os.path.exists(nomeArquivo):
        raise Exception("Arquivo inexistente")
    
    arquivo = open(nomeArquivo,"r")
    
    return arquivo.readlines()

def escreveArquivo(nomeArquivo:str, entradaDado:str)-\>None:

    with open(nomeArquivo,"a") as file:
        file.write(entradaDado)
        file.write("\n")
        file.close()
```

test file:

```
import pytest
from src.lerEscreveArquivo import *
from src.palindromoClass import *
from unittest.mock import MagicMock
from pytest import raises

@pytest.fixture()
def mock_open(monkeypatch):
    mock_file = MagicMock()
    mock_file.readlines = MagicMock(return_value = "test line")
    mock_open = MagicMock(return_value = mock_file)
    monkeypatch.setattr("builtins.open",mock_open)
    return mock_open

def test_LerArquivo(mock_open, monkeypatch):
    mock_exists = MagicMock(return_value = True)
    monkeypatch.setattr("os.path.exists",mock_exists)
    result = abreArquivo("blah")
    mock_open.assert_called_once_with("blah","r")
    assert result == "test line"

def test_throwsExceptionWithBadFile(mock_open, monkeypatch):
    mock_exists = MagicMock(return_value = False)
    monkeypatch.setattr("os.path.exists",mock_exists)
    with raises(Exception):
        result = abreArquivo("blah")
```

my problem is how to unittest:

```
def escreveArquivo(nomeArquivo:str, entradaDado:str)->None:
```

??
i've been made a long search on internet but i cannot find a way to properly test this function
Answers cover thing dont are applicable in this context

I'm intend to build a test that i can use @pytest.fixture and set mock operations and monkeypatch atribbutes

Comment: Does this answer your question? -- https://stackoverflow.com/a/34677735/13261176

Comment: In theory, no. patch is used to mock a class. In this code i don't use class in write/read file...

Comment: Check https://docs.python.org/3.3/library/unittest.mock.html#mock-open

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Probably, this is what you want

```
import pytest
import builtins
from unittest.mock import mock_open

def abreArquivo(nomeArquivo:str)->list[str]:
    try:
        with open(nomeArquivo,"r") as arquivo:
            return arquivo.readlines()
    except FileNotFoundError as e:
        raise RuntimeError("Arquivo inexistente") from e


def test_LerArquivo(monkeypatch):
    m = mock_open(read_data="test line\n")
    monkeypatch.setattr(builtins, "open", m)
    result = abreArquivo("blah")
    m.assert_called_once_with("blah","r")
    assert result == ["test line\n"]

def test_escreveArquivo(tmp_path):
    file = tmp_path / "test"
    data = "this is a test"
    escreveArquivo(file, data)
    with open(file) as f:
        actual = f.read()
    assert actual == f"{data}\n"
```

Comment: Hi, Diego! Thanks to share your opnion. In that case I want to test the WRITE function. Is this case if i run the code my test, of readFile,  is collected and pass, without worries. But, thinking on writeFile, we have two test cases: 1) i have to test if a file was opened in the correct way, like "w". 2) test if the message was wrote

Comment: Added test_escreveArquivo

Comment: I had seen a resolution in this regard. However, my plan was to test the function using mocks and delve deeper into the use of "setattr" to actually open a file in "w" mode and test the writing. I searched a lot on the internet but I can't find it using the fixtures. Anyway, thank you for the help, this way is very smart.

Comment: Well, this is a unit test, testing the side effects of your function, and it's independent of its implementation. Anything else you do, it won't be.