# mock_open for open called inside of instance method in imported class

Tags: python, python-3.x, mocking, python-unittest

I am trying to test a method in a class that I have that writes an output to a file. However, to prevent the test method from actually writing a new file, I would like to mock the writing out process and instead analyze the call_args of the mock() object (i.e. what would have been written out). I know I could analyze a file output, but I feel like this way is cleaner and I would like to understand what I'm doing wrong here to improve my unit testing skills.

I have 2 files, model.py and test_model.py.

model.py:

```
class Builder:
    def __init__(self, input_template_map, output_filename, output_dir=""):
        self.input_template_map = input_template_map
        self.output_filename = output_filename
        self.output_dir = output_dir

    def build(self):
        output = ""
        # some code that adds to the output that requires files to be read
        # (i.e. calls open(somefile, "r"))
        with open(f"{self.output_dir}/{self.output_filename}.EB", "w") as f:
            f.write(output)
```

and test_model.py:

```
import unittest
from unittest.mock import mock_open, MagicMock, patch
from model import Builder

class ModelTest(unittest.TestCase): 
    @classmethod
    def setUpClass(cls):
        cls.builder = Builder({...}, output_filename="test_out", output_dir="outputs")

    def test_build(self):
        m = mock_open()
        with patch("model.Builder.build.open", m, create=True):
            self.builder.build()
        print(m.mock_calls)
        print(m.return_value.write.call_args)
```

However, without fail, mock_calls is empty and return_value.write.call_args returns none. I've tried every possible target for the first argument of patch that I can think of...including test_model.Builder.build.open, test_model.Builder.open, model.Builder.open, etc. with the same result. I feel like I'm missing something, though I read the documentation on mock_open, the different namespaces with unittest.mock, and many stack overflow questions that have been asked. Any help would be appreciated!

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How do I mock an open used in a with statement (using the Mock framework in Python)?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1289894/how-do-i-mock-an-open-used-in-a-with-statement-using-the-mock-framework-in-pyth)

Comment: I saw that post, and I don't think any of the responses had what I was looking for. If I tried to use __builtins__.open or any variant of f'{__name__}.open', patch would not be able find the module. In addition, I don't want to test whether open('foo', 'w') was called, but rather the specific open statement in the build method.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The mock object returned by `mock_open()` is for the context manager for `open`. To deal with mocked calls to the file object that `open()` yields, call the mock itself. Here's an example that passes and properly prints the calls to write:

```
class ModelTest(unittest.TestCase): 
    @classmethod
    def setUpClass(cls):
        cls.builder = Builder({...}, output_filename="test_out", output_dir="outputs")

    def test_build(self):
        m = mock_open()
        with patch("builtins.open", m):
            self.builder.build()

        # checking that the open call was as expected
        m.assert_called_with("outputs/test_out.EB", "w")

        # checking that the write call was as expected
        handle = m()
        handle.write.assert_called_once_with("")

        print(handle.mock_calls)
```

Instead of `m.return_value` use `m()`. `builtins.open` here worked in my tests.

Comment: Thank you so much, this gets me much closer! I do have an additional question though. The builtins.open worked for me to get it to mock opens, but is there a way to mock only opens called with the 'w' flag? I have a couple of open statements called in methods called in build() earlier in the code, but they're only used to read files. If this is an entirely separate issue, I'd be happy to make another post though.

Comment: You can create a second mock. Remember that `open` is used as a context manager, so a call to open will yield an IO object. Create a mock for the file `file_mock = mock_open()()` (*Note that we are 'calling' the mock*). Then can create a side effect function `def side_eff(*args, **kwargs): file_mock if args[1] = "w" else open(*args, **kwargs)`. Apply the side effect function to `open_mock = MagicMock(side_effect=side_eff)`. Then use the `open_mock` in your patch call. You can look at `file_mock` as the handle to see calls on the file, and `open_mock` to inspect the open call.

Comment: Although it's not generally good practice to have IO operations in your unit testing, you might want to use this as a template to mock return values from reading a file. Also, you can take advantage of OOP patterns to abstract away built-ins from your classes which would help a lot in testing.

Comment: Thank you for the follow up reply! I ended up following that suggestion and creating a separate method entirely for writing out to file, and that was much easier.  The side effect strategy was promising, but on my end it caused infinite recursion I think because it was trying to mock the open method within the side effect as well.